# Question about the word “melt” meaning “to blend"

Tags: meaning

> *Why do you melt chocolate with milk?*

In this sentence, I can't figure out the nuance between melt and blend. Does it meant that you must heat the mixture? Or, are they synonyms?

In the dictionary, the definition for melt in this sense is:
**To blend or cause to blend gradually**

Comment: Where did this sentence come from? Did you find it in the dictionary, write it yourself, find it in a cookbook, or find it somewhere else?

Comment: I am on a mission to downvote any post that contains the phrase "the dictionary", lionel.    Native speakers do use the phrase *the dictionary*, but we shouldn't emulate them here on ELL. There are many dictionaries, all of them created by editors and lexicographers, and so there is really no such master reference as "the dictionary".  If you found this definition in *a* dictionary, please cite it by name.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Making ELL a better place, one vote at a time. (I just hope you’ll upvote questions that cite specific dictionaries with equal zeal – particularly when the OP takes the trouble to look up words in multiple dictionaries and quote more than one.)

Comment: @J.R. It won't be my mission, but I will, and do.

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence you've provided "melt" says that you're doing more than blending.

"Melting" chocolate with milk will cause it to blend but by saying "melt" rather than "blend" you're saying that you're adding heat to the action.

Take the sentence instead read:

> Why do you blend chocolate with milk?

This gives a different meaning which implies taking the two things and combining them through some process.

Again, Melt in this context means that you are blending the chocolate and the milk by heating them up and mixing them together.

Comment: There’s powdered chocolate, which some might say could “melt” into the milk when stirred.

Comment: But to '_melt_' something and to '_blend_' something can be different. Say I'm melting chocolate with milk. The final product I'll get is molten chocolate. But if I blend it with milk, I may end up getting chocolate milk. This contradicts your answer.